# Redirect a content of the directory to another directory in parent folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect `http://www.example.com/myfolder/dir1` to `http://www.example.com/myfolder/dir2`.

But I want to use `.htaccess` in dir1 i.e. `http://www.exmaple.com/myfolder/dir1/.htaccess`.

Comment: Please don't ask duplicate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this this rule as 1st rule in `/myfolder/dir1/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myfolder/dir1/

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myfolder/dir2/$1 [L,R]
```